# How can I pass content using Intent and OnActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

My problem is:

I have 2 classes:

- FirstActivity.java
- SecondActivity.java

When I click on `fab button` on `FirstActivity` i want to pass a `String variable` to `SecondActivity` and go to `SecondActivity`. In `SecondActivity`, I will receive that String and Toast it up.

How can I do this ? **Thanks you so much**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fab buttons onClick method

```
//creating and initializing an Intent object
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

//attach the key value pair using putExtra to this intent
String user_name = "Jhon Doe";
intent.putExtra("USER_NAME", user_name);

//starting the activity
startActivity(intent);
```

In your SecondActivity onCreate method

```
//get the current intent
Intent intent = getIntent();

//get the attached extras from the intent
//we should use the same key as we used to attach the data.
String user_name = intent.getStringExtra("USER_NAME");
```

Source: https://zocada.com/using-intents-extras-pass-data-activities-android-beginners-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Put your this code in you fab button `onClickListener`

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(mContext, SecondActivity.class);
mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
mIntent.putExtra("key", "Your value");
startActivity(mIntent);
```

And on `SecondActivity.java` receive like

```
String value = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("key")
```

`key` is unique name for particular variable you can give as your requirement.

if you have pass variable then simple put your variable like

```
String str = "This is my meesage";
mIntent.putExtra("key", str);
```